# Comet comes into Earth's orbit and the inside gives access to multiple parallel Earths

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for the title of a book telling the story: an object which at first seems to be a comet comes into orbit of Earth. It turns out to be a tube? that is a fixed size but inside it is endless. It gives access to multiple parallel Earths.

The title was one word (like "eos" => not). I read this book in the early 90s. I'm not sure if I read it in English or Dutch but I think the original language was English.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide] to see if you can [edit] in any extra details.

Comment: John Rennie has given you the answer but in case you didn't already know there is a sequel to _Eon_ called _Eternity_ and also a prequel called _Legacy_.

Comment: @MikeScott you should be aware of our story-id duplicate policy and know that we don't close story id's as dupes without confirmation from the OP. This may be close but not be it.

Comment: This is not the answer, but I can't help but observe the abstract description's resemblance to the movie [Coherence](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2866360/).

Comment: See OP comment below confirming duplicate status.

Answer (score 37):

[Eon by Greg Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_(novel)).

It is an asteroid not a comet, but otherwise it's a perfect fit to your description. The asteroid contains six normal chambers, but in the seventh chamber:

> the end of the Stone's seventh chamber opens out into a vast cylindrical corridor ("The Way"), a "pocket universe" that extends far beyond the physical limit of the asteroid, and may possibly be infinite.

Comment: There were two other books dealing with the Stone; _Eternity_ and _Legacy_, same author. (oops, saw that @BennyHill already mentioned them)

Comment: Thank you all, EON, i checked was the title i was looking for. Knowing there are two sequels is just perfect! The other mentioned titles i`ll check out as well because they seem interesting as well. THX again Pieter

Comment: @Pieter It looks like you accidentally created two accounts. Please [request an account merge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can accept this answer (you'll see a checkmark icon on the left of the post -- click it to accept it).

Comment: @Pieter You can accept answers by ticking the check-mark below the up and downvote buttons if they have solved your problem. This will show future users that they don't need to do research on this topic, as it has been sufficiently answered, and gives the answerer a +15 rep. You even receive a neat +2 rep yourself.